# Adding AsyncTask class to activity crashes app

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I recently needed to use AsyncTask in an activity in my android app. So I made a class inside the activity and extended AsyncTask in that class.

But now, whenever I launch that particular activity, my app immediately crashes. I tried putting the whole `onCreate()` of the activity in a try, catch block, but no exceptions were raised. The app just crashes immediately when I launch that activity, without any explanation in the LogCat.

This started happening after I added the AsyncTask class mentioned above. Also, the AsyncTask part is NOT executed when the activity is launched, it executes on pressing a button. What could be going wrong? I have added the relevant code below:

```
public class ListViewA extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {try{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        //computation
    }

    private String[] top() {
        new RetreiveFeedTask().execute(ctr,ctz);
        return er;
    }

    public class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, String[]> {
        String[] q;

        protected String[] doInBackground(Context... params) {
            //computation
        }

        protected void onPostExecute() {
            er=q;
            gff=true;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I found an error in LogCat which looks important:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.exampleapp/com.example.exampleapp.ListViewA}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: your doInBackground() parameter is wrong. second add a Override tag to the onPostExecute(result). the result of doInbackground() is a paramter to onPostExecute. your onpostExecute does not have any parameter. third call super.onPostExecute(result); pls check the link @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Is there anything either side of the log cat which gives a hint as to where in your code the NPE is occuring?

Comment: Looking at that error, it could well be in the declarations section of the Activity, might be an idea to post that.

Comment: @NeilTownsend Yes you are right. The error is in the declaration section at line `Context ctz=getApplicationContext();`..

Comment: As could be seen on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtlRNNhane0&index=4&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE you sholdn't use your asynctask as inner class. It will result on memory leak everytime that the user rotates the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your edit is interesting and suggests that there is a problem in the instantiation of the Activity, in which case I would look at the variable declarations quite carefully. However, in the absence of any of that code (or more `onCreate` code), or the surrounding lines from the logcat, it's hard to be more specific.

As @Raghunandan says, the way your AsynTask is constructed is incorrect, it should be something like:

```
public class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, String[]> {
    String[] q;

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Context... params) {
        //computation
        return result; // result is of type String[]
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        // do something with result ...
        er=q;
        gff=true;
    }
}
```

A secondary point is your `top()` function, which returns `er`. I am guessing that you want it to wait until the AsyncTask is complete and then return `er`, which has been calculated by the AsyncTask. However, what it will do at present is to set the AsyncTask and then immediately return `er`: it won't wait for the AsyncTask to complete.

To achieve that, you probably need to split the button press action into two phases:

1. Create and run the AsyncTask
2. OnPostExecute in the AsyncTask calls the code which currently uses the `er` returned by top.

Comment: As the AsyncTask code is not accessed on activity startup, shouldn't the problem lie elsewhere?

Comment: @vergilcorleone It could well lie elsewhere, but I've tried to point out the potential issues in the code you have posted. It might be good to post more of `onCreate` to see if anything can be spotted there ...

Comment: @vergilcorleone it does not matter where you load your asynctask unless it is loaded from your main UI thread. It should be loaded on the ui thread

Answer (score 0):

I have a `private class ReadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>` in my program. 
Under that, I have: 
 `protected void onPreExecute()`, 
`protected String doInBackground(String... params)`, and 
`protected Void onPostExecute(String result)`. 
The first two have `@Override` above them. The only one I'm ACTUALLY using though, is `doInBackground`. I'd first really just try adding `@Override` to `doInBackground()`. Next, try changing `Context` to `String`.

EDIT: 
You are also missing the function to grab an activity. Again, this is simply what I'm doing in my code and a few examples I saw online:

```
 
public RetreiveFeedTask(Activity activity) {
```

`this.activity = activity;`

`}`

Something like that.

Comment: But I am passing Context as parameter to the AsyncTask.

Comment: `Context` SHOULD work. I just was saying that, just in case passing it a `Context` was causing an issue. The main thing really to try first is adding `@Override`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ListViewA extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        //computation

        new RetreiveFeedTask().execute(ctr,ctz);
    }
    ...

    public class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, String[]>{

         @Override
         protected String[] doInBackground(Context... fileName) {
             //computation
             String[] q;
             //Know that fileName is an Array
             return q
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
             //do something with the result
         }
    }
...
}
```